# Double exponential function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $1$ and $Y=ln(X)$. The distribution of $X$ will be $f(x)=e^{-x}$. Now I want to find the distribution of $Y$. So say:

$y=x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ so $x = e^y$ with $x'=e^y$. Now the distribution function of $Y$ will be: $g(y) = e^{-e^y} \cdot e^y$.

Why is this not correct? Because we now the *double exponential function* in this form as: $g(x) = 1-e^{-e^{-x}}$. Even if we evaluate the integral of above expression from $0$ to $x$, we get:
\begin{align}
\int\limits_0^x e^{-e^y} \cdot e^y dy = \frac{1}{e} - e^{-e^y}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log$ is a strictly increasing differentiable function, we have
$$\begin{align*}F_Y(y) &= \mathbb P(Y\leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(\log X \leqslant y)\\
&= \mathbb P(X\leqslant e^y)\\
&= F_X(e^y)\\\end{align*}$$
The density of $Y$ is obtained by differentiating:

$$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy}F_X(e^y) = F_X'(e^y)\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy}e^y =  e^{-e^y}e^y = e^{y-e^y}. $$

Answer (score 0):

If $$X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$$ such that $$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x > 0, \lambda > 0,$$ and $$Y = g(X) = \log X,$$ then the density of $Y$ is given by $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} \right|.$$  In this case, $g^{-1}(y) = e^y$ and we find $$f_Y(y) = \lambda e^y \exp(-\lambda e^y ) = \lambda \exp(y - \lambda e^y), \quad -\infty < y < \infty.$$  This shows that $-Y$ is a Gumbel distribution (also known as an extreme-value distribution, or double-exponential distribution).